# What happens if a dummy variable is 0 or 1 in the training set, but always 1 in the test set

Tags: regression, categorical-data, random-forest, train

I have regression models (linear, lasso and Random forest), and there is a feature that is 0 or 1 in the training set (same number of occurrences approximately) and has a small effect on the target outcome variable (when is 1, the value of the target variable is slightly less).

However, in the test set, this feature always has a value of 1.

Since I've added that feature, my models perform way less good. I am wondering what is happening ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if your **target** variable contains only ones in the test sample, is that you do not learn anything about performance of your model in cases where your target is zero. Simple example: *"always return 1"* model will have 100% accuracy and very good results on other error metrics, but many of those performance metrics would be quite useless if you know that your test sample didn't contain any zeros. You wouldn't learn about performance of your model in terms of false positives. If choosing your model based on test set metrics, you would tend to choose models that predict more ones in total.

If your **features** take only ones in the test sample, then it is not fully representative for your data. If your dataset is small, then it is possible that it does not represent all the possible combinations of your features, but it should be  reasonably representative for the real-life data. The good thing is that it's a known-unknown, so you know what you don't know about the model's performance. The bad thing is that you still don't know how does your model behaves in some scenarios. What you can do is to

1. get more data for your test set (best option if available),
2. move (preferably random) part of your training sample that contains zeros to the test sample,
3. use $k$-fold cross-validation (especially if your sample is relatively small), i.e. split your data randomly for $k$ equal parts and for $i=1,...,k$ iterations, in each case take the $i$-th part as your test sample and use the rest of the parts as your test sample. By using randomized procedure you make it more likely to have balanced test sets.

If you can't obtain more data, or resample your data, then you should at last acknowledge in your report that performance of your model is unknown in such-and-such scenario.

Comment: I think he's referring to features, independent variables, not outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer. I was indeed talking about features (Independant variables). 

Is it correct to say that my model overfits on the training set (learns how to handle 1 and as well 0 for that feature), but then is lost with new data that contains only 1 ?

Comment: @firepod you model can, or cannot overfit on training set, the problem is that with such test set as you describes it would be hard to fully check if it overfits or not.